# Forcing global npm in package.json scripts

Tags: node.js, npm

A great feature of npm has caused me a bit of a headache yesterday.
npm runs commands in the `scripts` block of `package.json` from `node_modules/.bin` if it can.
Given something like this in a `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "npm-version": "npm --version"
},
"dependencies": {
  "publish": "0.5.0"
}
```

i'm getting something like this:

```
$ npm install
$ npm run npm-version

> root@1.0.0 npm-version /home/cg/root
> npm --version

2.15.1
$ npm --version
3.8.0
```

So a random dependency can overwrite the version of npm that's used in commands in the `scripts` block. It's not really surprising, but definitely tripped me up.

Is the only way to get around this to add npm with the desired version as a dependency to my project or is there a way to tell npm not to use `node_modules/.bin` for a specific command?

I'm sorry if this has been asked already, but it turned out to be really difficult to find the right keywords for this problem, i'm sure someone has run into this before.